# iOS NSURL queuing mechansim for multiple requests from file

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurl

I am very new to iOS development, but I would like to make an app that has two table view controllers (columns): both are a row of images that act as links. The first would be a column of YouTube videos and the second a column of websites. I would like to have all these listed in a file `file.txt` listed like so: `V, http://youtube.com/example` `W, http://example.com`

There would be a long list of those, the V meaning its a video (for the video column) and W for the websites. Now, I understand how to being the single file in, but what happens afterwards is my concern. Can I read each line into some sort of queue and then fire the NSURL request for each one consecutively? How can that be done with NSURL? Is there perhaps a better approach?

Comment: You can achieve by using `GCD` or `NSOperationQueue` or you can use a third party library "ASIHTTP.." to make url request consecutively.

Comment: I have used ASI, it is now deprecated, which is why I am looking for a more proper way to do this.

Comment: Fine then go for `GCD` or `NSOperationQueue`. Perform every request within `NSOperation` and add those operation instance into queue.

Answer (score 1):

There are two questions for me:

1. Is a text file really the best format?

   I might suggest a plist or archive (if the file is only going to exist only in your app's bundle and/or documents folder) or JSON (if it's going to live on a server before delivering it to the user) instead of a text file. It will make it easier to parse this file than a text file. For example, consider the following dictionary:

   ```
   NSDictionary *dictionary = @{@"videos"  : @[@"http://youtube.com/abc", @"http://vimeo.com/xyz"],
                                @"websites": @[@"http://apple.com", @"http://microsoft.com"]};
   ```

   You can save that to a plist with:

   ```
   NSString *documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
   NSString *plistPath     = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"files.plist"];

   [dictionary writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
   ```

   You can add that file to your bundle or whatever, and then read it at a future date with:

   ```
   dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
   ```

   You can, alternatively, write that to a JSON file with:

   ```
   NSError  *error    = nil;
   NSData   *data     = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
   NSString *jsonPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"files.json"];
   [data writeToFile:jsonPath atomically:YES];
   ```

   You can read that JSON file with:

   ```
   data       = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:jsonPath];
   dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
   ```

   Either way, you can get the list of videos or web sites like so:

   ```
   NSArray *videos   = dictionary[@"videos"];
   NSArray *websites = dictionary[@"websites"];
   ```
2. Now that you have your arrays of videos and websites, the question then is how you then use those URLs.

   You could do something like:

   ```
   for (NSString *urlString in videos) {
       NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: urlString];
       // now do something with the URL
   }
   ```

   The big question is what is the "do something" logic. Because you're dealing with a lot of URLs, you would want to use a `NSOperation` based solution, not a GCD solution, because `NSOperationQueue` lets you control the degree of concurrency. I'd suggest a `NSOperation`-based networking library like [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking). For example, to download the HTML for your websites:

   ```
   NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
   queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 4;

   for (NSString *urlString in websites)
   {
       NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
       NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
       AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
       [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

           // convert the `NSData` responseObject to a string, if you want

           NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

           // now do something with it, like saving it in a cache or persistent storage
           // I'll just log it

           NSLog(@"responseObject string = %@", string);

       } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
           NSLog(@"error = %@", error);
       }];
       [queue addOperation:operation];
   }
   ```

   Having said that, I'm not sure it makes sense to kick off a ton of network requests. Wouldn't you really prefer to wait until the user taps on one of those cells before retrieving it (and for example, then just open that URL in a `UIWebView`)? You don't want an app that unnecessarily chews up the user's data plan and battery retrieving stuff that they might not want to retrieve. (Apple has rejected apps that request too much data from a cellular connection.) Or, at the very least, if you want to retrieve stuff up front, only retrieve stuff as you need it (e.g. in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`), which will retrieve the visible rows, rather than the hundreds of rows that might be in your text/plist/json file.

Frankly, we need a clearer articulation of what you're trying to do, and we might be able to help you with more concise counsel.